# Angles clockwise or not

Tags: trigonometry

Let's consider I have following angles:

(Start)0, -350, -300, -250 , -200, -180, -145, -110, -80, -30 degree

```
    -110 degree o  o -80 degree        
- 145 degree     o        o    -30 degree  (End)

-180 degree o          o  0 degree (Start)

-200 degree   o        o -350 degree

-250 degree     o  o  -300 degree
```

I am identifying these given angles are clockwise or not, or if there is any counter clockwise point.

If we look at the picture above and start drawing a line which starts at 0 and moves to 30 , it seems to be clockwise.

But if consider Mathematical Quadrants, how they are interperated, which suggests 0 degree lies in first quadrant, which suggests that this is point not in clockwise direction.

I believe all points other than 0 degree are clockwise, if this is wrong assumption, can someone put some light on the problem?

Comment: "If we look at the picture below [...]" There is no picture in your post.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche picture above :)

Answer (score 1):

By convention, all positive angles are counterclockwise and negatives are clockwise. The final quadrant has nothing to do with that.

For instance, +30° and -330° land in the same quadrant.

Comment: My bad, I have updated the data points

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist: that doesn't change my answer.

Comment: So, This assumption is right i.e the Angle 0 only in the dataset which is in ccw direction, and rest are cw?

Comment: Obviously, the direction of $0°$ is undefined as it has no sign.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Consider the simpler

$0,180,0,180,0,180...$

Clockwise? Counterclockwise?

Comment: Clockwise direction

Comment: And if written $0, -180, 0, -180, 0, -180$?

Comment: Counter Clockwise but i am not sure the proof

Comment: But what is the difference between 180 and -180?

Comment: Magnitude is same but not the direction

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if you have only the final position shown, you cannot decide whether it was achieved clockwise or counterclockwise, you can always reach the final angle from both directions.

Comment: But i have following points to make circle 0, -350, -300, -250 , -200, -180, -145, -110, -80, -30 in degrees , i am trying to identify direction

Comment: i have updated the data